# Discrete Math - Vertex Coloring

Tags: graph, discrete-mathematics

I have a homework which I was given about a week ago. The thing is, I don't understand what my teacher taught but he gave us a homework...

A = {a,b,s}, B = {b,h,t}, C = {a,t,s}, D = {h,t,s}, E = {a,b}, F = {b,t,s}

How to create a minimal vertex coloring, which A,B,C,D,E and F are the vertexes?

I do know how to color a vertex but I don't know how to create the graphs from the given sets. Any helps? I tried looking on the internet but I don't come across a question like this.

Comment: Perhaps the sets A, B, and so on in the question, which apparently are the verticesof some graph, are meant to be connected by an edge if and only if they intersect?

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is to be interpreted in such a way that the vertices `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` are meant to be connected if and only if they intersect, an optimal coloring has 5 colors.

The resulting graph is *almost* the complete graph on 6 vertices - `{E,F}` and `{E,D}` are the only edges which are missing. That being said, it contains the complete graph on 5 vertices via the subgraph induced by `{A,B,C,D,F}`. Consequently, any vertex coloring cannot use less than 5 colors. In total, the coloring

```
F : 1
A : 2
B : 3
C : 4
D : 5
E : 1
```

is a 5-coloring of the graph which is optimal.